# IdentityServer not showing custom view

Tags: identityserver3

I am trying to follow this guide https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/advanced/customizingViews.html by adding an `assets` folder to the root of my web application and placing a `login.html` there.

However when the navigation brings me to `https://localhost:44343/identity`, the login page I see is still the default one.

What am I doing wrong, why doesn't it pick up the overridden login page? I'm using IdentityServer3 2.5.0.

Comment: can you try to change name of file, `_login.html` instead of `login.html`.

Comment: Tried earlier and didn't work, thanks for the suggestion though. Found what was the problem meanwhile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution:

As I'm using `IdentityServerServiceFactory` I need to configure the Default View Service to look at the `/Assets` folder:

```
var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory();

// more code...

var assetsDirectory = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Assets");
factory.ConfigureDefaultViewService(new IdentityServer3.Core.Services.Default.DefaultViewServiceOptions { CustomViewDirectory = assetsDirectory });
```

Comment: This works for login.html and an associated *.css file.  Is there a convention location for the bootstrap and angular libraries Identity Server uses?

Comment: If you're trying to customise the welcome page and can't work out why it's not working, it's a known issue, see: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/942